# Azure function dependency injection invocation exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, pnp-core-sdk

**Update 02-03-2023 2**

Found a workaround that fixed the issue for me. Posted it as an answer.

**Update 02-03-2023 1**

I have managed to pinpoint that the exception occurs when setting the certificate in `PnPCoreAuthenticationCredentialConfigurationOptions`

```cs
X509Certificate = new PnPCoreAuthenticationX509CertificateOptions
{
    Certificate = certificate
}
```

My theory at the moment is that the certificate data might not be persisted properly when `Function1` is initialized with dependency injection.

---

I am building an Azure Function V4 using dotnet6 where I make use of PnPCore to authenticate to a SharePoint Online.

I authenticate to SharePoint Online using `X509Certificate` stored in an Azure Key Vault. Everything regarding the ADD registration, certificate, and key vault permissions are all fine. I have verified access to SharePoint Online works using PowerShell.

My Azure Function has a `Startup` class which binds the configuration and secrets to access SharePoint Online and does dependency injection.

However when the function executes I get this error message:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target 
of an invocation.

Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "SharePointApp": {
    "ClientId": "6f5020cb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "A6q****l6",
    "TenantId": "7bcac91e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ListServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/TestSite/SomeLibrary",
    "AzureKeyVault": {
      "Uri": "https://contoso-keys.vault.azure.net/",
      "AppCertificateKey": "My-integration-app-DEV"
    }
  },
  "PnPCore": {
    "HttpRequests": {
      "UserAgent": "PnPCoreSDK"
    },
    "PnPContext": {
      "GraphFirst": "false",
      "GraphCanUseBeta": "false"
    },
    "Sites": {
      "SiteToWorkWith": {
        "SiteUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `Startup`:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
using Contoso.Function;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PnP.Core.Auth.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Contoso.Function
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private static IConfiguration _configuration = null;

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var spOptions = new SharePointAppConfiguration(); // Custom class for "SharePointApp" in local.settings.json.
            _configuration.GetSection("SharePointApp").Bind(spOptions);
            var coreOptions = new PnPCoreOptions();
            _configuration.GetSection("PnPCore").Bind(coreOptions);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(spOptions);

            builder.Services.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.PnPContext = coreOptions.PnPContext;
                options.HttpRequests = coreOptions.HttpRequests;

                foreach (var site in coreOptions.Sites)
                {
                    options.Sites.Add(site.Key, site.Value);
                }
            });

            builder.Services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication(options =>
            {
                var azKeyVault = new CertificateClient(spOptions.AzureKeyVault.Uri, new ClientSecretCredential(spOptions.TenantId, spOptions.ClientId, spOptions.ClientSecret));
                var certificate = azKeyVault.DownloadCertificate(spOptions.AzureKeyVault.AppCertificateKey);

                options.Credentials.Configurations.Add("x509certificate", new PnPCoreAuthenticationCredentialConfigurationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = spOptions.ClientId,
                    TenantId = spOptions.TenantId,
                    X509Certificate = new PnPCoreAuthenticationX509CertificateOptions
                    {
                        Certificate = certificate
                    }
                });
                options.Credentials.DefaultConfiguration = "x509certificate";
                options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith",
                    new PnPCoreAuthenticationSiteOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationProviderName = "x509certificate"
                    });
            });
        }

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }
    }
}
```

My `Function`:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Services;

namespace Contoso.Function
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly IPnPContextFactory _pnpContextFactory;

        public Function1(IPnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory)
        {
            _pnpContextFactory = pnpContextFactory;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            using (var context = _pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SitesToWorkWith"))
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I remove the `builder.Services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication` part the function runs fine and of course fails when getting to `using (var context = _pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SitesToWorkWith"))` because no authentication was provided.

Am I missing some vital part in `Startup` or is my `local.settings.json` missing some properties?

Comment: Setting 'break on all exceptions when thrown' might help you find out exactly what is null and when - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p8E2.png

Comment: Usually that object reference error is thrown whenever you try to get a value from a property but the class of the property is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me. For some reason `AddPnPCoreAuthentication` did not work, so found an example from [this sample code](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/blob/dev/samples/Demo.AzFunction.ManagedIdentity/Startup.cs) which explicitly sets an authentication provider in `AddPnPCore` instead.

So my Startup ended up looking like this:

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services
        .AddOptions<SharePointAppConfiguration>()
        .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.GetSection("SharePointApp").Bind(settings);
        });

    builder.Services
        .AddOptions<PnPCoreOptions>()
        .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.GetSection("PnPCore").Bind(settings);
        });

    var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var spOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SharePointAppConfiguration>>().Value;
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(spOptions);

    builder.Services.AddPnPCore(options =>
    {
        var azKeyVaultClient = new CertificateClient(spOptions.AzureKeyVault.Uri, new ClientSecretCredential(spOptions.TenantId, spOptions.ClientId, spOptions.ClientSecret));
        var certificate = azKeyVaultClient.DownloadCertificate(spOptions.AzureKeyVault.AppCertificateKey);
        var authProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(spOptions.ClientId, spOptions.TenantId, certificate)
        {
            ConfigurationName = "x509certificate"
        };
                
        options.DefaultAuthenticationProvider = authProvider;

        foreach (var site in options.Sites)
        {
            site.Value.AuthenticationProvider = authProvider;
        }
    });
}

public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```